# order strings which end with number with a few exceptions that end with non-numerical character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using this script:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    SomeString NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'X1'
    UNION 
SELECT 'X10'
    UNION 
SELECT 'X2'

-- undesired result
SELECT * FROM #Temp ORDER BY SomeString

-- desired result
SELECT * FROM #Temp 
ORDER BY LEFT(SomeString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SomeString)-1), -- alphabetical sort 
CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(SomeString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SomeString),LEN(SomeString))) -- numerical sort
```

See more at: http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

To achieve a 'sensible order' like this (see statement desired result):

```
X1
X2
X10
```

Unfortunately, this does not work should the original string contain anything that does not end with a number (rare exceptions). In other words in such a scenario:

```sql
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'X1'
    UNION 
SELECT 'X10'
    UNION 
SELECT 'X2'
    UNION 
SELECT 'X2a'
```

PS:

A possible crude solution:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp 
ORDER BY LEFT(SomeString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]',CASE WHEN SomeString LIKE '%[a-Z]' THEN SomeString + '0' ELSE SomeString END)-1), -- alphabetical sort 
CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(SomeString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]',CASE WHEN SomeString LIKE '%[a-Z]' THEN SomeString + '0' ELSE SomeString END),LEN(SomeString)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the only numbers in each value make up the number that you want to sort by (as opposed to there being numbers prior to the numbers at the end, such as `X5Y10` or `X5Y10A`), then your best bet is to compute/extract the numeric portion at `INSERT` / `UPDATE` time (which is infrequent) rather than at `SELECT` time (which is typically much more frequent):

1. Create a UDF, `dbo.ExtractNumber()`, to extract the numeric portion of the string value. While UDFs are typically less than ideal for performance, this will only be executed upon `INSERT`, and optionally upon `UPDATE` if this field is updateable.
2. Add a Non-Persisted Computed Column to your table named `SortField` (or whatever), and defined as:

   ```
   dbo.ExtractNumber([SomeString])
   ```
3. Create a Non-Clustered Index on that Non-Persisted Computed Column, `SortField`.
4. In your query, do `ORDER BY [SortField]`.

Given the example data, all starting with `X`, it is implied that the alpha portion of the string is not relevant. If that is not the case and the alpha portion *is* to be sorted by first, and then the numeric portion (as truly numeric), then this would require two UDFs and two Non-Persisted Computed Columns, but still only one index. And technically a UDF is probably not required to extract the alpha portion as that can be a simple `SUBSTRING`, starting at 1, and using `PATINDEX` to find the position of the first numeric to feed the 3rd parameter for the `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I have no control over insert/update. The temp table and inserts above where just used to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @csetzkorn I understand the use of the temp table to communicate the issue, but I do not understand what is meant by "I have no control over insert/update". What I am suggesting requires no specific handling of events. I was just saying that the value is automatically computed when those events occur. And I was pointing that out because from a performance perspective, it is much better to calculate them once, or at least not often, as compared to calculating them for each and every query. My suggestion is even more appropriate when _not_ using a temporary table :-).

Comment: Thanks. I am confused now. You suggest the use of a Non-Persisted Computed Column. However, this would be calculated at 'select time' not during insert/update as mentioned in point 1. Also what would be the UDF's content. This is mainly what the question was about ...

Comment: @csetzkorn It _would_ be at SELECT time _if_ you selected that field. But my suggestion was to create a Non-Clustered Index on that field, and that would have to be pre-calculated, but only used for a sort, not a select (I believe). As for the UDF itself, that cannot be answered accurately until you clarify if the alpha part before the number matters for the sorting, and if any potential alpha part after the number matters, and if so, how it influences the order. Please update the question being very specific (sample output really helps) about the expected behavior.

Comment: @csetzkorn Thanks for accepting, but what did you end up doing, exactly? I had some code started that was pretty efficient for extracting the numbers, but wasn't sure what to do with it since I didn't know how characters before and/or after the numeric portion should affect the ordering.